# Connect an asp.net or webservice application to SAP B1

Tags: asp.net, web-services

How can we connect an asp.net or webservice application to SAP B1?

Can anyone give a clear sample code and an example to connect any module which is available in SAP B1?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must have DIAPI installed
Refer to SAPbobsCOM

Sap connection

```
        SAPbobsCOM.Company oCompany = new SAPbobsCOM.Company();
        conectado = int.MinValue;
        oCompany.Server = "localhsot";
        oCompany.CompanyDB = "DB";
        oCompany.DbUserName = "SQL_USER";
        oCompany.DbPassword = "PASS_SQL";
        oCompany.UserName = "USER_SAP";
        oCompany.Password = "PASS_SAP";

        //language
        oCompany.DbServerType = BoDataServerTypes.dst_MSSQL2012;
        oCompany.language = BoSuppLangs.ln_Spanish_La;

        conectado = oCompany.Connect();
        if (conectado != 0)
            string error = oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription();
```

With this object you have the base to open any module of sap with the DIAPI

Example sap document

```
SAPbobsCOM.Documents oDocuments = oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oQuotations);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SAP B1 Service Layer configured and running, then I would advice you to use it over SAPbobosCom. It has better performance but note, that you can not run SQL queries. The Service layer is a REST api and uses the oData protocol.